# SpecFlow ISpecFlowOutputHelper throws Unable to resolve service for type

Tags: c#, specflow

I am using Specflow+livingDoc for our reporting.
And am working on testing the APIs but the report doesn't mentions the sent request and responses. So I was thinking if there's a way to add onto LivingDoc reporting and I found this: https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/outputapi/outputapi.html

I am injecting it in the stepdefs constructor

```
private readonly ISpecFlowOutputHelper _specFlowOutputHelper;

        public StepDefs(ScenarioContext scenarioContext, IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory, ISpecFlowOutputHelper outputHelper)
        {
            _scenarioContext = scenarioContext;
            _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
            _specFlowOutputHelper = outputHelper;
        }
```

But when I try running the scenario, I get this exception:

```
Message: 
    System.InvalidOperationException : Unable to resolve service for type 'TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.ISpecFlowOutputHelper' while attempting to activate 'AcceptanceTests.Steps.StepDefs'.

  Stack Trace: 
    CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound)
    CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite(ResultCache lifetime, Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
    CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(ServiceDescriptor descriptor, Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, Int32 slot)
    CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
    CallSiteFactory.CreateCallSite(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
    <>c__DisplayClass7_0.<GetCallSite>b__0(Type type)
    ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
    CallSiteFactory.GetCallSite(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
    ServiceProviderEngine.CreateServiceAccessor(Type serviceType)
    ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
    ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
    DependencyInjectionTestObjectResolver.ResolveBindingInstance(Type bindingType, IObjectContainer scenarioContainer)
    lambda_method58(Closure , IContextManager , String )
    BindingInvoker.InvokeBinding(IBinding binding, IContextManager contextManager, Object[] arguments, ITestTracer testTracer, TimeSpan& duration)
    TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStepMatch(BindingMatch match, Object[] arguments, TimeSpan& duration)
    TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStep(IContextManager contextManager, StepInstance stepInstance)
    TestExecutionEngine.OnAfterLastStep()
    TestRunner.CollectScenarioErrors()
    Feature.ScenarioCleanup()
```

Any help please?

Comment: Which NuGet packages do you have installed for this project?

Comment: SolidToken.Specflow.DependencyInjection, SpecFlow.Plus.LivingDocPlugin, SpecFlow.xUnit

Answer (score -1):

I had to register this interface in my startup services, and it works ok now.

Comment: Could you please add some details, how you registered the interface? So people in the future can comprehend this answer?

Comment: Agreed with @TheTanic. It is perfectly fine to answer your own question. I've done this with my own questions before.